# Nodejs битый jpeg при скачивании с другого сервера Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, node.js, jpeg

Пытаюсь скачать картинку, а она битая выходит( Пробовал варианты  [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734047/cannot-save-a-remote-image-with-node-js-and-request), [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries) и т.п. , результат одинаковый. Пробовал другие картинки, с разных серверов.

```
var input={
    url: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_025.jpg',
    dest: 'test.jpg' 
}
request({
        url:input.url,
        encoding: 'binary'
},function(err, response, body){
    if(err)return callback(err);
    fs.writeFile(input.dest, body, 'binary', function(err){
        console.log(err||'Ok');
    });
});
```

==>
слева оригинал, справа результат выполнения кода выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В винде всё работает нормально, в амазоне тоже (`cat /etc/*release*
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"`)
В чем может быть дело?

**UP:**
слева оригинал, справа результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UP2:**
node -v
Работает в v0.10.36 и v0.12.0, не работает в v4.2.1

Comment: На скриншоте видно, что первые несколько байт отличаются. Не могли бы Вы посмотреть их в HEX редакторе?

Comment: Не только первые несколько. Много байт в полученной картинке вот такими символами � в нотепаде (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, как будто мы win1251 читаем как utf). но ведь картинка не может быть в неправильной кодировке..

Comment: На http://open-file.ru/types/jpg написано, что первые несколько байт могут выглядеть, как "яШяа". А чтобы узнать, могут ли они выглядеть так, как справа, нужно видеть их HEX коды.

Comment: прикрепил картинку

Comment: Похоже, файл сохранён в кодировке 'utf-8'. То есть в текстовом, а не бинарном режиме. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB Может быть причина в разных версиях nodejs?

Comment: Вполне может быть. Работает в v0.10.36 и v0.12.0 не работает в v4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Oceinic Насчет изменившегося api вы были неправы, а насчет utf-8 - правы. Картинки были битыми из за того, что лежали в папке temp, где были еще автоматически сгенерированные html-отчеты, которые отдавались примерно так:

```
router.get('/html_reports/*', function(req, res, next){
    var report_filename=req.path.split('/html_reports/')[1];
    fs.readFile('temp/'+report_filename, 'utf-8',..callback - {res.end(result)} ..  );
});
```

Картинки тоже попадали в эту конструкцию. Но некоторые картинки всё же скачивались уже битыми (только на node v4.2.1 ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) - не ясно, каким образом они в таком формате оказывались в пресловутой папке temp (код приведен в вопросе), но этого мы не узнаем, т.к. проблема больше не воспроизводится( Решилась сама собой. осталось только пара битых файликов на память.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые форматы хранения файлов содержат заголовок в первых трёх байтах файлах. В первом случае заголовок относится к формату JPG (бинарный файл), а во втором случае файл сохранён в формате UTF-8 (текстовой формат).
Учитывая, что на других компьютерах тот-же код работает правильно, вероятно на разных компьютерах используются разные версии nodejs. И причина ошибки - в изменившемся API.

**UPDATE**:

> The NodeJS docs stress that the binary string encoding is heavily discouraged since it will be dropped at some point in the future.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823722/how-to-decode-binary-encoded-string-into-raw-binary-buffer

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback не наблюдаю изменений API(

Comment: А я не наблюдаю там кодировки 'binary'.